# Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, launchpad

Running `sudo apt update` on my Ubuntu 20.04 gives the following error output on all launchpad ppas:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x focal InRelease                                             
Hit:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease                                 
Hit:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                   
Hit:5 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org focal InRelease                                        
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                 
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                               
Hit:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu focal-infra-security InRelease                               
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                
Hit:10 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu focal-infra-updates InRelease                               
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]                             
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                             
Hit:12 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease                                       
Hit:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                               
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]           
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease                                 
  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.85), connection timed out
Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/beineri/opt-qt-5.15.2-focal/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pypy/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/blender/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/graphics/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/multimedia/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/utilities/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/vlc3/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stk/dev/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/uget-team/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xtradeb/apps/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Fetched 672 kB in 30s (22.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.85), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/beineri/opt-qt-5.15.2-focal/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pypy/ppa/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/blender/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/graphics/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/multimedia/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/utilities/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/vlc3/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/stk/dev/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/uget-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/xtradeb/apps/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**Does somebody else have the same error when running `sudo apt update`?**

UPDATE 2021-12-25:

Using a vpn somehow makes me being able to run `sudo apt update` without any errors.

Comment: Run : `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0` and run `apt update` again.

Comment: @someone I don't use a modem. The `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0` command didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update` instead of `sudo apt update` Are you using cellular data or wireless wifi? Do you use BSNL? I found that ;BSNL don't support ipv6 which is causing the errors.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem solved of itself and I couldn't find any reason why the problem went away. Written by the author of this question.

Comment: I have the same issue. 
and checked the  sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0

Comment: i remove all ppa sources as a quick workaround

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, but only with VPN connection (IP 163.XXX.XXX.XXX). With no VPN (IP 77.XXX.XXX.XXX) its Ok.
Probably problem in launchpad.net firewall (or traffic filter, or something like that).